# The top Navigation getting distorted

Tags: 2010, navigation, top-link-bar, sharepoint-designer

i have new fresh sp2010 and i created a teams site . I added some navigations link to the top navigation bar . But sometimes the top nav bar appears to be expanded . I have not made any changes ,its pure OOTB . Any idea what may be the reason ?  [image]

Comment: How does that look? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: If you could post a screenshot of what is happening that would be the best way to get an answer. There are lots of reasons why this behavior might be happening.

Comment: please find screenshot

Comment: I would first check this biggish white html tag with developer tools in the browser.

Comment: i used developer tool , firebug but nt able to figure wat is the prob .

Comment: This happens only in IE , when i get vertical scroll bar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue and fixed after August 2013 Update.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a81422c5-c6c6-4cb4-b463-6b93472246d0/top-navigation-error-in-clean-sharepoint-2010-install?forum=sharepointadminprevious